# Is it possible for a LWC to listen to changes in a Lightning Record Page?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a Lightning Web Component that is part of a Lightning Record Page for an Opportunity.

I would like to be able to listen to the change of the Opportunity Stage in order to determine the visibility of some elements in my LWC.

Is there a way that I can listen to field changes on a Lightning Record Page?

There looks like there is the ability to listen to the "force:recordSaveSuccess" event, but only for Aura Components if I understand that right. Is there something similar for LWC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **getRecord** wire adapter from the **Lightning Data Service** to fetch the record data and track the fields that you are interested in. You can also use a **getter** function to access the **field values** and perform any logic or rendering based on the field changes.

Here is an example of a **Lightning Web Component** that listens to the change of the **Opportunity Stage** and displays a message based on the stage value:

HTML:

```
<template>
        <lightning-card title="Opportunity Stage Listener" icon-name="standard:opportunity">
                <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                        <template if:true={opportunity.data}>
                                <p>Opportunity Name: {name}</p>
                                <p>Opportunity Stage: {stageName}</p>
                                <p>{message}</p>
                        </template>
                        <template if:true={opportunity.error}>
                                <p>Error: {opportunity.error}</p>
                        </template>
                </div>
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';

import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Name';
import STAGE_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.StageName';

export default class OpportunityStageListener extends LightningElement {
        @api recordId; // get the current record id from the Lightning Record Page
        @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [NAME_FIELD, STAGE_NAME_FIELD] })
        opportunity; 

        get name() {
                return getFieldValue(this.opportunity.data, NAME_FIELD); // get the name field value
        }

        get stageName() {
                return getFieldValue(this.opportunity.data, STAGE_NAME_FIELD); // get the stage field value
        }

        get message() {
                // return a message based on the stage field value
                switch (this.stageName) {
                        case 'Prospecting':
                                return 'You are in the early stage of the sales process.';
                        case 'Qualification':
                                return 'You have identified the customer&apos;s needs and pain points.';
                        case 'Needs Analysis':
                                return 'You are proposing a solution that meets the customer&apos;s requirements.';
                        case 'Value Proposition':
                                return 'You are demonstrating the value and benefits of your solution.';
                        case 'Id. Decision Makers':
                                return 'You are engaging with the key decision makers and influencers.';
                        case 'Perception Analysis':
                                return 'You are addressing any objections or concerns that the customer may have.';
                        case 'Proposal/Price Quote':
                                return 'You are presenting a formal proposal or quote to the customer.';
                        case 'Negotiation/Review':
                                return 'You are negotiating the terms and conditions of the deal.';
                        case 'Closed Won':
                                return 'Congratulations! You have won the deal.';
                        case 'Closed Lost':
                                return 'Sorry, you have lost the deal.';
                        default:
                                return 'Unknown stage.';
                }       
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tushar. I was just trying that out. I didn't realise that the wire reran on change of the record. Good new. Thanks.